# Stop SearchView in Toolbar when user clicks recycler row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, searchview

I am trying to implement a SearchView in a Toolbar which has a NaviagtionDrawer such that the RecyclerView is ONLY displayed when the user clicks on the search icon. Then I want the RecyclerView to vanish and the searchView to collapse when the user selects a row in the RecyclerView. When the search is not being done, the main functionality of the app is taking place.

I have gotten the search filtering to work and the `onClick()` in the adapter does its job. However, the only way I can keep the RecyclerView from hogging the screen is to call the `RecyclerView.setAdapter()` method in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` which can't be right. However, I cannot get it to shutdown so that is a one-time solution; once up, it stays up!

Here is my main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/base_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          tools:context="com.lampreynetworks.cpa.CPA_Activity"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_search_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/borderLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_connect_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:text="Please take a reading now with the medical device you have connected to your CareSpan PHG app. Be sure to select the right patient from the list above."
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/borderLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:choiceMode="none"
            android:stackFromBottom="false">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the layout for the include containing the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                            
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                                 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                                 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"                                                 
    tools:context="com.lampreynetworks.cpa.CPA_Activity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbarBackground"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>e
```

I have the xml for the RecyclerView rows (using Cardview) and that appears as it should.

So the basic questions are

- how do I hide the RecyclerView until the user clicks on the Toolbar
  search icon, and
- how do I re-hide it when the user clicks on a row in
  the RecyclerView of displayed filtered items?

Comment: I have a way to solve the problem but I feel it is a hack. I make the RecyclerView visibility View.GONE until the menu search item is clicked then I make it View.VISIBLE. When the user clicks on a row, I use the Toolbar.collapseActionView() and trap the MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() to set the visibility to View.GONE. THis cannot be the intended way to get this behavior.

Comment: I have found no better solution. I have changed the CoordinatorLayout to a LinearLayout and place the GONE on the DrawerLayout and make the RecylcerView visible. I reverse the process when the user clicks on a row. It works, but it still feels like a hack.